# Using 3rd Party Libraries in C++

Tags: c++, static-libraries, codeblocks

I'm totally spinning my wheels with getting a couple of 3rd party libraries to work with my c++ programs. I'm looking for some general advice (40,000 foot level) about the general steps that one needs to take when implementing libraries.

First, some specifics: I am using code::blocks in Windows as my IDE. I like this IDE and really don't want to switch to anything else if I don't have to (I've tried visual c++ and also some things in linux). The libraries that I am trying to use are GMP and crypto++.

OK. What I *think* I know is this: After downloading the library, I unzip the file to a folder. I've been unzipping directly to C:\ with each zip file extracted to its own folder (e.g. c:\cryptopp and c:\gmp). I think that the next step is to build the library, but this is where I get totally stuck. How is this done? There are no executable files among those extracted. From what I can tell, I believe that I do this in code::blocks, but I have no idea how?

Finally, assuming that I can get this done, which I believe creates the .lib files, the last step before actually using the library in my code, is to link into the library. This part, I believe that I understand.

So, my question is broad: do I understand this process overall? And if so, how do I go about building these libraries, if in fact that it the thing that I am missing.

Thanks very much for indulging my ignorance. I'm totally rudderless right now and despite hours and hours on google, I'm making no progress. Also, feel free to correct anything that I have stated as fact that is not correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are lucky, there's a .sln file somewhere in the folders of these libraries. Open this file in code::blocks (if it supports the format) and compile. If not, I'd just try to find the pre-compiled libraries on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Usually libraries have a special file called makefile in them, and are built with a utility called [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) (or one of it's variations, whatever works uder windows). 
Usually all you have to do is to run Make in the directory where you have unpacked the source files, and it will do the rest itself.

Answer (score 1):

If those libraries you mention (GMP and crypto++; disclaimer: I'm not familiar with either of them) don't have project files for code::blocks then you may still be able to compile them under Windows with MinGW.

If you have installed MinGW you use the MinGW shell to navigate to the appropriate directories  which would be `/c/cryptopp/` and `/c/gmp` in your examples - The MinGW shell works like a Unix shell, and has different naming conventions.

Then you need to compile the libraries. Check whether there's a Makefile in those directories, if there isn't you can check whether there's a `configure` script, which will generate the Makefile. If you have the Makefile you can type `make` which will compile the libraries with MinGW's port of the GCC compiler.

When the compilation is complete you should have a library in the form of a .a file (say `libcryptopp.a`) that you can link to your project. In code::blocks you would set the linker path (the `-L` command line option in GCC) to `C:\cryptopp\bin` or wherever the library has been compiled, and then add `libcryptopp.a` to the list of libraries you want to link (this is associated with the `-l` option in GCC). The convention is to leave out the lib prefix and the .a extension, so you would just add `cryptopp` to your library list. In the end your linker options should look like `-LC:\cryptopp\bin -lcryptopp` along with the

Also, to be able to use the libraries you need to add the path to the headers directory to the include path of your project. This is associated to the `-I` command line option in GCC, so your compiler's command line options would have something like `-IC:\cryptopp\include` somewhere.

Of course, all of the above assumes that you use code::blocks with GCC. If you're using it with VisualC++ then the principles are the same, but the specific steps differ.

Comment: I'm starting to think that building libraries is a conspiracy to make people like me crazy. OK, I've installed minGW, launched it, and navigated to /c/cpplibs/gmp/.  There are no makefiles, but there is a configure file. So I type configure at the prompt. It starts out all right, but then crashes with an error "could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details"? What is minGW if not a working compiler? Every step I take just leads to an error more cryptic than the last error. What am I doing wrong? Very frustrated...  Thanks.